# why does gnu nano keeps opening up the bashrc file during startup of terminal?

Tags: command-line

Every time I open a new terminal. The .bashrc file opens on gnu nano and I had to save and exit to get to the terminal window. I am unable to find the reason for this.

When I tried diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc

```
husarion@test-612836-2307:~$ diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
21a22,23
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
33a36,37
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
37a42
> 
42a48,49
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
46c53
< #force_color_prompt=yes
---
> force_color_prompt=yes
62a70,71
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
76a86,87
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
88a100,101
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
91a105
> 
109a124,125
> nano ~/.bashrc
> 
117a134,138
> . /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://master:11311
> export ROS_IPV6=on
> . /home/husarion/ros_workspace/devel/setup.sh
>
```

Comment: The simplest explanation would be that one of your shell initialization files contains a command like `nano .bashrc`

Comment: @Jeyesh I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to include the output of `diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` (which shows changes made to the `.bashrc` file in your home directory). The most likely shell initialization file to have been modified accidentally in a way that produces an effect every time you open a terminal window is `.bashrc` itself.

Comment: i tried diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc and copied the output to the question

Comment: you have several lines `nano ~/.bashrc` ...